# Code inside spoiler markup is not hidden

Tags: bug, design

Inline code inside spoiler markup is never hidden.

> Text is hidden but `code` is not.

```
>! Text is hidden but `code` is not.
```

(Used in the wild [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33570/how-do-i-output-a-count-of-all-files-with-tty-in-the-filename-in-the-linux-dir/33588#33588).)

Comment: Yeah, I see that it works elsewhere (SO).

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly fixed now: code in spoiler is hidden. There's still a glitch: the code part has a different background from the rest of the text.

[image: code in spoiler]

Comment: This should be fixed in the production server build.

Comment: I'm upvoting this to stop Community bumping this question. Code in spoiler markup seems to be hidden fine now.